# MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. at Function.create()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update values into an object array(users) if it does not already exist in MongoDB. Here is my Schema:

```
    ownerid:{
        type: Number,
        required: 'This field is required'
    },
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    capacity:{
        type: Number
    },
    basePrice:{
        type: Number 
    },
    users:[{
        id: Number,
        price: Number,
        target: Number,
        frequency: Number
    }],
    filePath:{
        type: String
    },
    status:{
        type: String
    }
});
```

The following is my router method:

```
app.post('/userBid',urlEncodedParser,function(req,res){
        resName=req.body.resName;
        console.log(resName);
        Resource.find({"name":resName},{"users.id": userid},function(err,existingUser){
            if (!existingUser){
                console.log("already in queue");
                //res.render('userHome.ejs');
            }
            else{
                console.log("in update");
            Resource.update({'name': resName},
      {'$set': {
             'users.$.frequency': 1,
             'users.$.id': userid,
             'users.$.price': req.body.price,
             'users.$.target': req.body.target
       }},{'multi': true},
          function(err,model) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err);
        }
        return res.json(model);
 });

                }
        });


        });
```

I have tried using $push but that does not seem to work either. Also I can't use '0' instead of '$' as multiple users will be inserted by the users and I need to store them all.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue :**

Reason why we use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) is to update a specific object/few specific objects in an array field that meet our condition. So when you use any positional operators like `$` or `$[]` then in filter part of `.update({filterPart},{updatePart})` query you need to use a filter to find specific object in array. So for example if `id` field is unique in `users` array then you can use it to filter/find the object needs to be updated.

Try this below code :

```
app.post("/userBid", urlEncodedParser, function (req, res) {
  resName = req.body.resName;
  console.log(resName);
  /** Use findOne if `name` is unique.
   * Cause `existingUser` will be array, instead findOne will return an object or null - So you can just do if(existingUser)to check true values  */
  Resource.find({ name: resName }, { "users.id": userid }, function (
    err,
    existingUser
  ) {
    if (!existingUser) {
      console.log("already in queue");
      //res.render('userHome.ejs');
    } else {
      console.log("in update");
      Resource.update(
        { name: resName, "users.id": userid }, /** `"users.id": userid` is the only change needed */
        {
          $set: {
            "users.$.frequency": 1,
            "users.$.id": userid,
            "users.$.price": req.body.price,
            "users.$.target": req.body.target,
          },
        },
        { multi: true },
        function (err, model) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err);
          }
          return res.json(model);
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried using $push again turns out my problem was i wasn't referencing my array object properly. This worked when i did {$push:{ users: {id:userid, price:req.body.price, target:req.body.target}}} Also I think set wasn't working as the users field was null at that time. Thank you for the immediate solution though, much appreciated :)

Comment: @nikfuzz : You need to check for `if(err)` at `.find()` call. Also I've a question :: `console.log("already in queue");` will be executed if `.find()` returns documents, So you've implemented `.update()` in else that means no docs found for given filter, then again in else we're updating docs with the same filter - So how is that even working ? Additionally I think we can do it in one DB call rather than two, what is your whole functionality..